# How to configure Ruby ob Rails for XAMP server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xampp, server-configuration

I have installed Ruby On Rails Application on my harddrive, and i am using XAMPP server. But i was not able to configure it to use on XAMPP server, do Ruby on Rails run on XAMPP server or need some other server like webrick or lighttpd...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not run on XAMPP. It can be integrated in Apache by using [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html), but AFAIK it's not available for windows.

So, if you have windows, you'll have to use [mongrel](http://noobonrails.blogspot.com/2006/06/how-to-setup-mongrel-as-native-windows.html) or webrick or any other win32-compatible server. I think mongrel is best for you.